# Compiling Maven Project in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I am really new to using Maven and was wondering if there is a way to compile a project in Visual Studio Code. I can get it to run in the debugger and see the output I am expecting, yet I don't think it is actually building into a .jar when I do this.

Is there some way to do this from within Visual Studio Code? I am essentially looking for the same as the command "mvn assembly:assembly" does when going at it through command prompt.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any reason you are not using a Java IDE?

Comment: Visual Studios is meant for C++, C, C# or .NET kind of programming languages. Visual Studios therefore uses VS or GNU GCC compilers. It does not support Java JDK compiler maybe just Java JRE at run time. Eclipse is a good Java IDE.

Comment: Gotcha, I have just started to play with Visual Studio Code so I was testing some of the capabilities, I guess I will go back to Eclipse for these projects. Appreciate it!